# Ошибка открытия файла на чтение после установки прав через su

Tags: android, xamarin

Коротко. Копирую файл, устанавливаю права, открываю на чтение

```
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "cp", fromFile.AbsolutePath , toFile.AbsolutePath });
Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec(new string[] { "su", "-c", "chmod", "666", toFile.AbsolutePath });
using (FileInputStream fr = new FileInputStream(toFile))
{
  ...
}
```

Сваливается с ошибкой на `FileInputStream`

> /dir1/dir2/file.blablabla: open failed: EACCES (Premission denied)

Изначально у файла права на чтение только для `su` но в файловом менеджере я смотрю после выполнения команд у файла `toFile` права 666.

В чем может быть загвоздка?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Получилось вытянуть данные из проблемного фала.

`unreadFile` - Проблемный файл

`fullTempName` - Вытянутые данные

```
using (Java.Lang.Process p = Java.Lang.Runtime.GetRuntime().Exec("su")) {
using (DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.OutputStream))
{
  os.WriteBytes("cat \"" + unreadFile + "\"\n");
  os.Flush();
  os.Close();
  using (DataInputStream ins = new DataInputStream(p.InputStream))
  {
    byte[] buff = new byte[4096];
    int count = ins.Read(buff, 0, 4096);
    using (System.IO.FileStream fs = System.IO.File.OpenWrite(fullTempName))
    {
      while (count > 0)
      {
        fs.Write(buff, 0, count);
        count = ins.Read(buff, 0, 4096);
      }
      fs.Close();
    }
  }
}
```

Если есть другие способы, то прошу сообщить... Спасибо.